# Input ou raw_input?

Tags: python

Alguém sabe me dizer qual a diferença entre `input` e `raw_input` no Python e qual o modo adequado de usar os dois?

Answer (score 5):

A diferença é que `raw_input()` não existe no *Python 3.x*, enquanto `input()` existe. Na verdade o antigo `raw_input()` foi renomeado para `input()` e o antigo `input()` não existe mais(apesar de que pode ser simulado usando `eval(input()).`

Pelo que andei pesquisando, em *Python 2.x*, o comando `input()` "avalia" o contexto no qual a chamada foi feita. Segue exemplo:

```
>>> x = input()
"hello"
>>> y = input()
x + " world"
>>> y
'hello world'
```

Comment: "Qual é a diferença entre `raw_input` ...?" -"A diferença é que `raw_input` não existe". ... Eu diria que é uma diferença bem drástica!

Comment: Mas faltou explicar o que o  extinto `input`  faz n Python2

Answer (score 0):

O raw_input() retorna o valor digitado como string, já o input() retorna o valor como inteiro
Obs: input() só aceita números